# Failed to load resource:soy template {Not all code is in Soy V 2 syntax (found file simple.soy not in Soy V2 syntax). }

Tags: jira-plugin, soy-templates, atlassian-ui

I have two soy templates in my plugin one of them loads fine but other is not getting loaded with 500 Internal server error. I am attaching the error from console.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
    {namespace JIRA.Templates.Impacttemplate.ImpactRow}

/**
 * Render the information page for the Requirement Template.

 * @param actor : string
   @param impact: string
 *

 */

{template .renderImpactRow}

<tr class="impact-soy" data-key="{$impact}" >

    /*<td><a href="#" id="button"><span class="key">{$productName}</span></a></td>*/
    <td><span class="key">{$impact}</span></td>
    <td><span class="name">{$actor}</span></td>

</tr>
{/template}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could figure out the solution:

There should not be blank line after soy doc comment.

```
@param impact: string should be like @param impact : string
```

Here is the actual working code:

```
/**
 * Render the impact.
 * @param new_actor : string
 * @param impact : string
 */
{template .renderImpactRow}
<tr class="impact-soy" data-key="{$impact}" >

    <td><span class="key">{$impact}</span></td>
    <td><span class="name">{$new_actor}</span></td>
</tr>
{/template}
```

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason, you shouldn't have to declare the parameter type.